# ReSharper and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, resharper

How do I disable plugin ReSharper in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: Only reason i could think was that the code inspector gives a bit of information overload if you haven't had chance to modify the rules etc. My answer lets you keep the features but loose the noise from the inspector.

Comment: I've had to do this several times during our 'Pair programming' interview tests. Forcing people to learn R# under those conditions is a bit nasty!

Comment: Well, the non resharper users never like the fact that all my keyboard shortcuts are different...

Comment: @carra - you'd want to do that when you have a crappy computer at work and your solution is over 50 large projects and resharper literally hangs your machine every time you try and open an ASPX file :)

Comment: I think it's great that this question has been edited twice, and it's still not phrased in the from of a question.

Comment: @Carra, sometimes it's good to know which error messages come from Visual Studio and which come from ReSharper, so you can show fellow devs how essential ReSharper is. Incidentally, I work with, er, ReSharper-challenged people.

Comment: @MrBoJangles I've tried to convince my boss to give a license to all developers but to no avail. I did get a license myself though so I'm happy. It always feels like going back to the medieval times when working at a colleagues PC.

Comment: I guess some bosses don't want their developers to be productive or to free them from worrying about over 1,000 possible software bugs/issues so they can actually produce product. Tragically, some devs don't get it either. I'm glad you got your license at least. I did, too.

Answer (score 11):

Tools -> Add-In Manager -> Uncheck all the checks on the line that says ReSharper.

Comment: You can also use Ctrl-8 to enable/disable Resharper for the current code file. Useless fact of the day :)

Comment: @Jason: Definitely NOT useless!

Answer (score 2):

In Resharper 5.0 you have to go to Tools -> Options -> Resharper -> General -> Suspend.

Answer (score 1):

From toolbar

ReSharper > Options > Settings (under code inspection on left) > Uncheck "Enable code Analysis"

Do it this way and you can turn it back on when you see sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable it through the visual studio add-in manager: http://twi.im/OW